# R - strange order of geoms in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have written a small function that plots multiple glm's as forest plots with ggplot. Each model shares the same predictors, but have different dependent variables.

The function requires at least all glm-objects as parameter. Then a data frame is created which is used for the ggplot-procedure.

In my example, I have following data frame with the predictors "sex", "age" (alter3gr), socio-economic status ("ses") and experience ("f0103"). After "transforming" the glm's into a data frame, the results look like this example:

```
                   OR     lower     upper        p pa shape grp xpos
sex1        1.3253832 1.0735041 1.6372096  "1.33 **"  s     3   1    7
alter3gr1   1.0544569 0.8078543 1.3747014     "1.05" ns     1   1    6
alter3gr2   0.7042160 0.5372706 0.9212466    "0.7 *"  s     2   1    5
ses3_neu21  1.3270242 1.0274121 1.7129088   "1.33 *"  s     2   1    4
ses3_neu22  2.0043975 1.4394807 2.8009534    "2 ***"  s     4   1    3
f01031      1.5953467 1.2783964 1.9944690  "1.6 ***"  s     4   1    2
f01032      2.3780514 1.7175161 3.3307287 "2.38 ***"  s     4   1    1
sex11       0.9841822 0.7684196 1.2605188     "0.98" ns     1   2    7
alter3gr11  1.1778530 0.8731799 1.5964175     "1.18" ns     1   2    6
alter3gr21  0.7633293 0.5513314 1.0588159     "0.76" ns     1   2    5
ses3_neu211 0.9536030 0.7048865 1.3010905     "0.95" ns     1   2    4
ses3_neu221 1.1891460 0.8171171 1.7327086     "1.19" ns     1   2    3
f010311     1.4651668 1.1290179 1.9002631  "1.47 **"  s     3   2    2
f010321     1.7943022 1.2683576 2.5200254 "1.79 ***"  s     4   2    1
sex12       1.1614532 0.9089319 1.4852303     "1.16" ns     1   3    7
alter3gr12  1.1143240 0.8228899 1.5159289     "1.11" ns     1   3    6
alter3gr22  1.0179194 0.7411147 1.4032116     "1.02" ns     1   3    5
ses3_neu212 1.2271544 0.9002163 1.6913440     "1.23" ns     1   3    4
ses3_neu222 1.6178685 1.1085687 2.3713724   "1.62 *"  s     2   3    3
f010312     1.5175505 1.1722055 1.9637617  "1.52 **"  s     3   3    2
f010322     2.0459773 1.4624682 2.8472016 "2.05 ***"  s     4   3    1
sex13       0.6712958 0.4647907 0.9638335   "0.67 *"  s     2   4    7
alter3gr13  1.2343442 0.7809696 1.9911347     "1.23" ns     1   4    6
alter3gr23  1.1335450 0.7068902 1.8517144     "1.13" ns     1   4    5
ses3_neu213 1.1521867 0.7230082 1.9049441     "1.15" ns     1   4    4
ses3_neu223 1.8294885 1.0694548 3.1988430   "1.83 *"  s     2   4    3
f010313     1.2280278 0.8363800 1.7952537     "1.23" ns     1   4    2
f010323     1.8262125 1.1282033 2.8955135   "1.83 *"  s     2   4    1

'data.frame':   42 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ OR   : num  1.325 1.054 0.704 1.327 2.004 ...
 $ lower: num  1.074 0.808 0.537 1.027 1.439 ...
 $ upper: num  1.637 1.375 0.921 1.713 2.801 ...
 $ p    : Factor w/ 40 levels "0.7 *","0.89",..: 5 3 1 4 7 6 8 12 13 10 ...
 $ pa   : Factor w/ 2 levels "ns","s": 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ shape: chr  "3" "1" "2" "2" ...
 $ grp  : Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ xpos : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 6 5 ...
```

The different models are identified by the "grp" column, the predictors by the "xpos" column.

This is how I draw the ggplot:

```
plotHeader <- ggplot(finalodds, aes(y=OR, x=xpos, alpha=pa, colour=grp))+
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(-modelPlotSpace)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), position=position_dodge(-modelPlotSpace)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=p, y=upper), position=position_dodge(width=-modelPlotSpace), hjust=-0.1) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=axisLabels.y) +
  scale_y_log10(limits=c(lower_lim, upper_lim), breaks=ticks, labels=ticks) +
  coord_flip()
```

However, in the plot, the order of the models change for almost every x-position (predictor). Does anybody know why? I'd like to have the same order of my OR-values for each x-position...

[image: Multiple glm's with changing order of ORs]

**In case you like to reproduce any examples, you can download the R-script [sjPlotOddsMultiple.R](http://www.strengejacke.de/R-Stuff/sjPlot/sjPlotOddsMultiple.R) here.** In the script header is an example. If you run that example with `sjp.glmm(fitOR1, fitOR2, fitOR3)` everything looks fine. However, if you change the order of parameters to `sjp.glmm(fitOR1, fitOR3, fitOR2)`, the problem occurs.

Thanks in advance
Daniel

Comment: I cannot reproduce the example: `sju.wordwrap` is not defined.

Comment: I would recommend to strip your `plotHeader <-` call of unnecessary details, which refer to undefined data. This would be much easier than sourcing your script, which is quite huge.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't recognize that sju.wordwrap was missing, since it is part of my package and was already loaded. I updated the script and uploaded it now. I also cleaned the example a little bit, but left the position-dodge-parameter, because I don't know whether this might affect occurring problem?

Comment: Just a note: you are using `scales` package, you may want to add `require(scales)` to the script since that's not obvious.

Comment: Okay, here's what I figured out: change to `plotHeader <- ggplot(finalodds, aes(y=OR, x=xpos, colour=grp, alpha=pa))` (order within aes) and the order will be preserved (no idea why though). If that fixes your issue, I'll post this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seemed to be the issue! Script works now. @scales: the script is part of a package where the used functions of the scales package are imported via "importFrom" tag, that's why I forgot to include it in my "reproducible" example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the minimal example (`finalodds` taken as above):

```
ggplot(finalodds, aes(y=OR, x=xpos, alpha=pa, colour=as.factor(grp))) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), position=position_dodge(-0.4), width=0, size=0.8) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(1,1), guide="none")
```

[image]

The correct order is restored by changing the `alpha` and `colour` aes:

```
ggplot(finalodds, aes(y=OR, x=xpos, colour=as.factor(grp)), alpha=pa) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), position=position_dodge(-0.4), width=0, size=0.8) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(1,1.0), guide="none")
```

[image]

Comment: Since the x-scale is discrete, you cannot supply numeric values. That's why I have to use factors. I have uploaded the script that also contains an example code in the script-header (see my edits at bottom of my initial posting). You can reproduce the bug there...

Comment: Dangerously reminiscent of a comment, and not an answer. Expand.

Comment: I will look into the edited example and expand soon.